# Convert enum to Literal type alias in Python typing

Tags: python, enums, typing

Is there a way to type annotate a function or variable in Python in such a way it allows both an enum or Literal formed form the attributes of the enum?

```py
from enum import Enum
from typing import Literal


class State(str, Enum):
    ENABLED = "enabled"
    DISABLED = "disabled"

def is_enabled(state: State | Literal["enabled", "disabled"]) -> bool:
    if isinstance(state, str):
        state = State(state)
    return state == State.ENABLED
```

In other words, is there a way to obtain the alias for `Literal["enabled", "disabled"]` without having to rewrite all the keys of the enum?

Comment: maybe just state: State | str, and you don't need explicitly create a new State here.

Comment: That indeed is my backup option, bu it would be better to have the literal :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm afraid **there's no such way**. The first thing that comes to mind is iterating over enum's values to build a Literal type won't work, because [`Literal`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#parameterizing-literals) cannot contain arbitrary expressions. So, you **cannot** specify it explicitly:

```
# THIS DOES NOT WORK
def is_enabled(state: State | Literal[State.ENABLED.value, State.DISABLED.value]) -> bool:
    ...
```

There's an open [issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/781) on GitHub with the related discussion. Basically, you could have hardcoded literals for every Enum, but in that case, you need to update it in accordance with Enum updates, and one day it will be messy. So, I would either stick with `State | str` annotation or just `State` and expect your function to accept only enums.

Also, take into account that you do not need to explicitly create an Enum object to test its value, you can just write `"enabled" == State.ENABLED` as I mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The actual use case is a to serialize either strings or enums before sending them to the database! The example is quite simple :)